# How can I set the StatusBar to a certain background color, and the Header background color to another one in React Native with CreateStackNavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend

I'm currently trying to set this StatusBar color to this Pink, configured with 'light-content', but the rest of the header I'm trying to set to white.

[image: Example I'm trying to build.]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<StatusBar
  barStyle="light-content"
  backgroundColor="#ff00ff"
/>
```

References:

[statusbar#barstyle](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#barstyle)

[statusbar#backgroundcolor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#backgroundcolor)